# Created executable using Pyinstaller on ubuntu and running on SuSE12 SP4 throws issues for libreadline

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyinstaller, suse

Created an executable using pyinstaller on ubuntu 16.04 and trying to run it on SuSe 12 SP4 gives error at a certain portion of the code.
The code works like this:

- Its a flask app that receives the input from user over web
- Process those inputs and creates a .sh script and run that shell script
- Reads the output from the shell script and present it to the web as a return render

The executable was successfully created on the ubuntu machine and works successfully and no issues seens but when I use this executable on SuSe12 SP4, it starts but when it reaches the code where it runs the bash script, it throws the following error:

`sh: /tmp/_MEI369vhy/libreadline.so.6: no version information available (required by sh)`

I am really tired of looking for solutions and have done the following so far:

- Tried both --onefile and --onedir, no difference
- Tried creating the executable on SuSe12 sp4 itself but it throws a different error regarding subprocess not being found
- Tried finding the libreadline.so on Suse with no luck
- Tried creating an env on ubuntu 14 but too many dependencies errors

I'm finally out of suggestions and could use some help here. If you can please assist.

## Environment

Python 2.7.12

Ubuntu 16.04

SuSe12 SP4

Pyinstaller 3.6

**P.S. The code as a raw python code works flawlessly on SuSe 12 SP4 if i create proper build environment**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally solved it with some assistance from Rokm. The warning message above was not causing any issues but it was due to the environment variable not being passed to subprocess.
In order to solve this issue, I simply did the following:

```
###Add the following code to your existing code 
env = dict(os.environ)  # make a copy of the environment
lp_key = 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'  # for GNU/Linux and *BSD.
lp_orig = env.get(lp_key + '_ORIG')
if lp_orig is not None:
    env[lp_key] = lp_orig  # restore the original, unmodified value
else:
    # This happens when LD_LIBRARY_PATH was not set.
    # Remove the env var as a last resort:
    env.pop(lp_key, None)
```

Next, add the env variable to subprocess Popen command. Here is the full code for reference. This code will give you the output of the command and also return code aka exit code of the command. Also, you don't have to use any shelix or any other things to run it, simple .strip() command will do it for you. Hope you guys find it useful, enjoy. !!

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE,STDOUT
env = dict(os.environ)  # make a copy of the environment
lp_key = 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'  # for GNU/Linux and *BSD.
lp_orig = env.get(lp_key + '_ORIG')
if lp_orig is not None:
    env[lp_key] = lp_orig  # restore the original, unmodified value
else:
    # This happens when LD_LIBRARY_PATH was not set.
    # Remove the env var as a last resort:
    env.pop(lp_key, None)

cmd = raw_input('Enter your command:')
out = Popen(cmd.split(),stderr=STDOUT,stdout=PIPE, env=env)

t, y = out.communicate()[0],out.returncode
print('output : ' + str(t))
print ('Return Code : ' + str(y))
```

P.S. Unfortunately, cmd.split() will fail in some cases, ie when an argument has spaces, like cmd='/usr/bin/ls "/home/user/my directory"' will fail with cmd.split(). In that case, cmd = shlex.split(cmd, posix=True) will work better. But shlex.split() will fail when stdout is captured, hence there is no allrounder solution IMHO